# How to continue with Rest calls if the first one satisfies the condition?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I'm switching from plain Retrofit to RXJava because I have to make multiple REST calls. But I'm having trouble understanding how to do the following:

First I would like to call an endpoint that returns data validity and if new data has to be fetched I have to get the new data from 5 other endpoints. After all data is retrieved and saved I have to continue to a new Activity.

I know how to make one call, but I have no idea how to do the above. Tips or links to tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following simple approach that I use in my applications: **use Events**

In your `build.gradle` **module-level** file:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Then, simply create a `POJO` class that represents your event like this:

```
public class DataValidationEvent{
  private boolean isDataValid;

  public DataValidationEvent(boolean isValid){
     this.isDataValid = isValid;
  }

  public boolean isDataValid(){
     return isDataValid;
  }
}
```

Then, in your `HTTP Request` when you have received the response stating whether the data is valid (from that endpoint), notify some class or activity to do the next operation like make the expected `request`. Like this:

```
if(responseIsValid){
   EventBus.getDefault().post(new DataValidationEvent(true));
}else{
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new DataValidationEvent(false));
}

//obviously, you can simplify the above code to a one-liner 
//by passing the actual variable returned
```

Next, in the activity that you need to trigger other `http requests/operations`, do this:

```
@Override public void onStart(){
  super.onStart();

  EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override public void onStop(){
  super.onStop();

  EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Then finally, within the same activity that you registered for events above, you need to handle (`subscribe`) to the event like this:

```
@Subscribe
public void onValidResponse(DataValidationEvent event){
   //here you can call the next api request or start activity.
}
```

I know this might not do everything you want to do but should guide you towards an `Event-driven` solution that decouples your project using the popular `publisher/subscriber` design pattern!

Good luck and I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The quick-and-dirty functional solution, assuming `apiClient` is a retrofit client, and cacheData saves and returns the cached data object:

```
Observable<Data> dataObs =
  apiClient
  .isDataValid()
  .filter(data -> !data.isValid)
  .flatMap(oldData -> Observable.zip(
       apiClient.fetchA(),
       apiClient.fetchB(),
       apiClient.fetchC(),
       apiClient.fetchD(),
       apiClient.fetchE(),
       (a,b,c,d,e) -> cacheData(a,b,c,d,e))
  .switchIfEmpty(Observable.defer(() -> getFromCache()));
```

Keep in mind that this will make a call to the API each time it's subscribed to; you may want to limit the frequency of such calls.